# MongoDB Strange Find Behavior

Tags: mongodb

lets say:

this is I:
`db.collection.find( {'field1' : { '$in' : [ 'a', 'b' ]  } } )` -- returns 10, correct

this is II:
`db.collection.find( {'field2' : { '$in' : [ 'a', 'b' ]  } } )` -- returns 20, correct

this is (I or II):
`db.end_collection.find({'$or':[{'field1':{'$in':['a','b'] }},{'field2':{'$in':['a','b']}}}]})` -- returns 15 (some overlap, correct)

this is III:
`db.collection.find( {'field3' : { '$in' : [ 'c', 'd' ]  } } )` -- returns 30, correct

this is IV:
`db.end_collection.find({'$or':[{'field1':{'$in':['a','b'] }},{'field2':{'$in':['a','b']}}}], 'field3':{'$in':['c','d']}})` -- returns 12 (correct)

this is (I or II) and (III or IV):
`db.end_collection.find({'$or':[{'field1':{'$in':['a','b'] }},{'field2':{'$in':['a','b']}}}], {'$or':[{'field3':{'$in':['c','d'] }},{'field4':{'$in':['c','d]}}}]})` -- returns 60,000!!!! (incorrect of course)

How can it be, I add more selection criteria and instead of the items returned to be less, it's way more.

In short. get me (I or II) returns 15, get me (III or IV) returns 12, and: (I or II) and (III or IV) to be 60,000???

I experimented with the $and operator (which shouldn't be needed, because it is implied) but nothing came of it.

Comment: Can you try `db.end_collection.find({$and:[{'$or':[{'field1':{'$in':['a','b'] }},{'field2':{'$in':['a','b']}}]}, {'$or':[{'field3':{'$in':['c','d'] }},{'field4':{'$in':['c','d]}}]}]})` ? Your query was not formatted correctly and you need explicit `$and` when you are using the same operator. More here https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/query/and/

Comment: Thank youuuuuu. I didn't know i need to explicitly use $and if use the same operator (tho i could swear i tried it). Please add it as an answer so i can accept it.